# Invalid hook call error when using React function component from npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have a React function component, `SimpleComponent`, exported from `library` project and published on GitHub packages. This package is consumed in `consumer` project which simply renders `SimpleComponent`. If `SimpleComponent` is using React hook, it fails to render in `consumer` project and I get the following React hook related error:

`Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

`library` project: https://github.com/joshigaurava/library
`consumer` project: https://github.com/joshigaurava/consumer

Both projects use React, TypeScript and webpack. Package.json, TypeScript and webpack configs included.

`library` package version `0.0.1` contains `SimpleComponent` without React hook and it renders and functions fine in `consumer` project. ([`SimpleComponent` works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEkQs.png))

`library` package version `0.0.2` contains `SimpleComponent` with React hook and it fails to render in `consumer` project. ([`SimpleComponent` fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O8f6.png))

I see many others a facing similar issue and I have tried various things so far but nothing has worked:

- Ensured that there is a single dependency on react/react-dom in `consumer` project (`npm ls react`, `npm ls react-dom`)
- Ensured none of the issues listed at https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html have occurred
- People seem to have solved this issue with `npm link` or symlinks when using `npm file:` in dependencies, but in my case, `consumer` project is using `library` project by consuming an npm package and so this doesn't apply
- Foolishly tried exporting `SimpleComponent` in different ways - with or without `default` etc.

Now I wonder if this has something to do with how webpack is bundling the `library` project. But I am spending too much time on this issue and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

webpack config was the issue. React was being bundled in output. For anyone stumbling on this issue, following webpack config helped fix it:

```
externals = {
  react: {
    root: "React",
    commonjs2: "react",
    commonjs: "react",
    amd: "react",
    umd: "react",
  },
  "react-dom": {
    root: "ReactDOM",
    commonjs2: "react-dom",
    commonjs: "react-dom",
    amd: "react-dom",
    umd: "react-dom",
  },
};
```